# Can't update Symfony - Symfony Installer is already updated to the latest version

Tags: symfony

Any idea why I can't seem to update Symfony?

```
$ symfony -v

 Symfony Installer (1.5.4)
 =========================

$ which symfony
/usr/local/bin/symfony

$ /usr/local/bin/symfony self-update
// Symfony Installer is already updated to the latest version (1.5.9).

$ /usr/local/bin/symfony -v

 Symfony Installer (1.5.4)
 =========================
```

And FWIW

```
$ symfony -v

 Symfony Installer (1.5.4)
 =========================
```

Comment: Is it possible symfony is installed in 2 locations?

Comment: I would suggest to delete `/usr/local/bin/symfony` then try `symfony -v` again. If it show something, then like @AlvinBunk said, there is a duplicate. In which case, find it and delete it. Repeat the process untill none is left. Then download back symfony ot it's lastest version. Also, just in case, what is owner and group of your file?

Comment: @Preciel Yes, clearly there's a duplicate. But the version at `/usr/local/bin` is the more visible one. So, it would make sense to figure out why Symfony is checking a version at a different location and how that can be resolved. By deleting the copy at `/usr/local/bin` I'm going to have to reinstall and I'll still have this mysterious shadow copy.

Comment: Execute this command on your server `find / -iname "symfony"` it will return all files called `symfony` then if you exclude those in your projects, all that will be left are your simfony installers